# html file display at bottom position

Tags: javascript, html

I have added on my HTML page the content of a log file so when the log file has many lines, there is a scrollbar on my webpage.

I am trying to display my webpage with a scrollbar on the bottom position with this code but nothing is happening:

```
<html>
  <header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plannificateur</title>
    <style>
    p1  {
      font-size: 130%;
    }
    p2  {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
    </style>
  </header>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <h1>Liste</h1>
      <!-- DERNIER_UTILISATEUR -->
    </form>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <hr>
    <h3>Journal des évènements</h3>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('log').scrollIntoView();
    </script>
    <div id='log'>
        <object data="log.txt" style="width:100%;"></object>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The Horizontal scrollbar and Vertical scroll bar can be added easily by a combination of these 3 CSS attributes:

- ***overflow / overflow-x / overflow-y***   (Show scrollbar when content overflows defined margins)
- ***max-width***  (define maximum width)
- ***max-height*** (maximum height)

**Here is an example for showing both horizontal and vertical scrollbars:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plannificateur</title>
    <style>
    .log-file-viewer {
        max-width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        overflow: scroll;     --> shows scrollbar


             --- Other options for specifying scroll ---

        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="log" class="log-file-viewer">
        Log file contents here .....
        <br>
        Line 1: Hello! How are you doing? Hello! How are you doing?Hello!How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?
        <br>
        Line 2: Hello! How are you doing? Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?Hello! How are you doing?
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to set scrollbar to be displayed at bottom instead of  top position ?

Comment: Horizontal scrollbar will always appear automatically at the bottom of the element only. No specific setting required to make scroll bar appear at bottom. If the requirement is to keep the element that has the scrollbar at the bottom of the page, then the CSS attributes of margin or position can be used.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the same behavior. As on your picture, my scrollbar is on the top position, so I see the beginning of the content, not the end.